# Set of limit points of the set $\{ \sqrt{n\pi}-\sqrt{n}\} \subset \mathbb {R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits

What is the set of limit points of the set $\{\sqrt{n\pi}-\sqrt{n}\}$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$

I am not getting any idea how to proceed.

Comment: It's an increasing, unbounded sequence. It has no real limit points.

Comment: Hint: $$\sqrt{\pi n}-\sqrt{n}=(\sqrt{\pi}-1)\sqrt{n}.$$

Comment: Depends on what $\{x\}$ means here - it possibly means the fractional part of $x,$ here. Coming so soon after the word set, though, it is reasonable to assume it is sloppy set notation.  @GerryMyerson

Comment: Its a well known result (related to rotations in the circle) that of $x$ is an irrational number, then $nx- \lfloor nx\rfloor$ is dense in $(0,1)$. This problem has for sure been addressed in MSE.

Comment: @Oliver, sure, but does that have any bearing on the question OP is asking, with those square roots and the ambiguous brackets?

Comment: @Thomas, if it means fractional part, then the quantity is always between $-1$ and $1$, so the limit points can't form all of the reals (which was what was asked at the time I wrote my comment, though it has been changed).

Comment: Initially I want to mean by the third bracket is   just the set...@GerryMyerson got that right....But here in comment section I got to know another aspects of my notation and that's interesting...thanks Thomas and Oliver

Comment: @GerryMyerson: $\mathbb{N}=\{\sqrt{n^2}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ thus, $\{nx:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset\{x\sqrt{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your notation means, there are different answers.

**Case 1**: You mean the set $S=\{\sqrt{n\pi}-\sqrt{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Setting $x_n:=(\sqrt{\pi}-1)\sqrt{n}$, we see that this sequence is increasing. Therefore, if its underlying set has a limit point, it can only be the actual limit of the sequence. However, $\{x_n\}_n$ is clearly unbounded, so depending on what definition you prefer either the only accumulation point is $\infty$, or there is no limit point (if you are looking for real limit points).

**Case 2**: The more interesting interpretation is that you meant the limit points of the set $S=\{\{(\sqrt{\pi}-1)\sqrt{n}\}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$. In this case, let $\alpha:=\sqrt{\pi}-1$, which is clearly irrational, and set $T:=\{\{n\alpha\}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, which is obviously a subset of $S$ (obtained by only looking at perfect square $n$s). Weyl's equidistribution theorem implies that $T$ is dense in $[0,1]$ and therefore so is $S$ as a superset. Since clearly $S\subset[0,1]$, it follows that all numbers in $[0,1]$ are limit points.